# Symfony entitymanager refuses to insert one column

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to persist and flush a new entity into my database. However, one column: `tblCompaniesServicesId`, doesn't get inserted along with the other data, resulting in a `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tbl_companies_services_id' cannot be null` response.

When I `dd($entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions());` after persisting the new entity, I get this: (Note that `tblCompaniesServicesId` has a value of 12.)

```php
array:1 [
  "0000000013992b51000000003eb8a5e6" => TblCompaniesServicesContracts {#1500
    -tblCompaniesServicesContractsId: null
    -tblCompaniesServicesId: 12
    -tblCompaniesServicesDiscountsId: null
    -tblCompaniesId: 9999
    -tblCompaniesLocationsId: null
    -tblCompaniesCustomersId: 9999
    -contractOrdernr: null
    -contractName: "yeetus"
    -contractDate: null
    -contractPrice: null
    -contractPricetax: null
    -contractTax: null
    -contractPayed: "0"
    -contractUntil: null
    -contractActive: "1"
    -contractMonths: null
    -contractReminder: "0"
    -discountTitle: null
    -discountPrice: null
    -discountPercentage: null
    -discountPriceStartup: null
    -discountPercentageStartup: null
    -transactionId: null
    -responseId: null
    -responseStatus: null
    -responseStatusNl: null
    -responseCheck: null
    -responseTransactionid: null
    -responseAmount: null
    -responseCurrency: null
    -responsePayed: null
    -responseCustname: null
    -responseCustaccount: null
    -responseCustcity: null
    -contractMemo: null
    -contractAmountPerPeriod: "0.00"
    -contractPeriodInMonths: "1"
    -contractContractInMonths: "12"
    -contractTerminateWithinContract: "1"
    -contractNoticePeriodInMonths: "1"
    -contractExtendInMonths: "12"
    -contractStartupAmount: "0.00"
    -contractPayInOnce: "1"
    -contractPayInOnceDiscount: "10"
    -contractTerminated: "0"
    -contractTerminatedDate: null
    -contractPaymentDay: "1"
    -contractPaymentDayNextmonth: null
    -contractReversalFee: null
    -contractSignature: null
    -contractEmail: null
    -contractIban: null
    -contractIbanName: null
    -contractCredits: "0.00"
    -contractApproved: "0"
    -contractMd5: null
    -payproInstallmentId: null
    -pdfHash: null
    -createdAt: null
    -guardianFirstname: null
    -guardianLastname: null
    -guardianEmail: null
    -guardianBirthdate: null
    -guardianSignature: null
    -signupValue: null
    -service: null
    -customer: null
    -contractAffiliateId: null
    -serviceAmountFirstmonth: null
  }
]
```

The response I'm getting is this: (now `tblCompaniesServicesId` has no value.)

`An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tbl_companies_services_contracts (tbl_companies_services_id, tbl_companies_services_discounts_id, tbl_companies_id, tbl_companies_locations_id, tbl_companies_customers_id, contract_ordernr, contract_name, contract_date, contract_price, contract_pricetax, contract_tax, contract_payed, contract_until, contract_active, contract_months, contract_reminder, discount_title, discount_price, discount_percentage, discount_price_startup, discount_percentage_startup, transaction_id, response_id, response_status, response_status_nl, response_check, response_transactionid, response_amount, response_currency, response_payed, response_custname, response_custaccount, response_custcity, contract_memo, contract_amount_per_period, contract_period_in_months, contract_contract_in_months, contract_terminate_within_contract, contract_notice_period_in_months, contract_extend_in_months, contract_startup_amount, contract_pay_in_once, contract_pay_in_once_discount, contract_terminated, contract_terminated_date, contract_payment_day, contract_payment_day_nextmonth, contract_reversal_fee, contract_signature, contract_email, contract_iban, contract_iban_name, contract_credits, contract_approved, contract_md5, paypro_installment_id, pdf_hash, contract_created_at, guardian_firstname, guardian_lastname, guardian_email, guardian_birthdate, guardian_signature, signup_value, contract_affiliate_id, service_amount_firstmonth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, 9999, null, null, null, \"yeetus\", null, null, null, null, \"0\", null, \"1\", null, \"0\", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, \"0.00\", \"1\", \"12\", \"1\", \"1\", \"12\", \"0.00\", \"1\", \"10\", \"0\", null, \"1\", null, null, null, null, null, null, \"0.00\", \"0\", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tbl_companies_services_id' cannot be null`

The body from my request:

```
{
    "tblCompaniesServicesId": 12,
    "tblCompaniesCustomersId": 9999,
    "contractName": "yeetus"
}
```

`TblCompaniesServicesContracts` entity (only relevant attributes and methods, because of the character limit, you can see how big this entity is from the dump posted above):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * TblCompaniesServicesContracts
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_companies_services_contracts")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TblCompaniesServicesContractsRepository")
 */
class TblCompaniesServicesContracts implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tbl_companies_services_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $tblCompaniesServicesId;

    public function getTblCompaniesServicesId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->tblCompaniesServicesId;
    }

    public function setTblCompaniesServicesId(int $tblCompaniesServicesId): self
    {
        $this->tblCompaniesServicesId = $tblCompaniesServicesId;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Relevant function in my controller: (again, character limit)

```php
    public function addCompaniesServicesContracts(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, TblCompaniesServicesContractsRepository $tblCompaniesServicesContractsRepository, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorageInterface, JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager, TblCompaniesUsersRepository $tblCompaniesUsersRepository)
    {
        try {
            $decodedJwtToken = $jwtManager->decode($tokenStorageInterface->getToken());
            $user = $tblCompaniesUsersRepository->findOneByUsername($decodedJwtToken["username"]);
            $request = $this->transformJsonBody($request);
            $tblCompaniesServicesContracts = new TblCompaniesServicesContracts();
            $parameters = $request->request->all();

            if ($user->getCompany() == null) { // check if contract company id is same as company id of the user who requested
                throw new \Exception(403);
            }

            if ($user->getSuperAdmin() != true) { // check if user authorisation level is high enough
                throw new \Exception(403);
            }

            while ($parameter = current($parameters)) {
                if (key($parameters) == "tblCompaniesId") {
                    throw new \Exception(422);
                }
                else {
                    $newValue = $this->setContractValues($tblCompaniesServicesContracts, key($parameters), $parameter);
                    if (is_numeric($newValue)) {
                        throw new \Exception($newValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        $tblCompaniesServicesContracts = $newValue;
                    }
                }
                next($parameters);
            }

            if ($tblCompaniesServicesContracts->getTblCompaniesServicesId() == null) {
                throw new \Exception(422);
            }

            $tblCompaniesServicesContracts->setTblCompaniesId($user->getCompany());
            $entityManager->persist($tblCompaniesServicesContracts);
            //dd($entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions());
            $entityManager->flush();


            $data = [
                'status' => 200,
                'success' => "contract added",
                'companiesServicesContractsId' => $tblCompaniesServicesContracts->getTblCompaniesServicesContractsId(),
            ];
            return $this->response($data);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            switch ($e->getMessage()) {
                case 403:
                    $data = [
                        'status' => 403,
                        'errors' => "You shall not pass! Forbidden, access denied.",
                    ];
                    return $this->response($data, 422);
                    break;
                case 422:
                    $data = [
                        'status' => 422,
                        'errors' => "Data not valid",
                    ];
                    return $this->response($data, 422);
                    break;
                default:
                    $data = [
                        'status' => $e->getMessage(),
                        'errors' => "The foxes are on the loose, unknown error!",
                    ];
                    return $this->response($data, 422);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your variable names are long and confusing.  Are TblCompaniesServicesContracts and TblCompaniesServices two different entities and is there a relation between them?  If so you should be looking up tblCompaniesServicesId via the entity manager to get the actual entity then setting the entity into the contracts.

Comment: I know the names are long and confusing, I, unfortunately, don't decide the column names. TblCompaniesServicesContracts and TblCompaniesServices are indeed two different entities. TblCompaniesServicesContracts and TblCompaniesServices do not have a relation, TblCompaniesServicesId can refer to a nonexistent TblCompaniesServices.

Comment: I suppose you could try adding a dd($tblCompaniesServicesContracts) in your controller just to see if the id is being set.  You got that funky loop going on and I really can see what likes like $tblCompaniesServicesContracts = $newValue; are supposed to be doing.  Might try starting with something easier just to get an understanding of how the Doctrine ORM is supposed to work?

Comment: TblCompaniesServicesId is just an integer and not a foreign key, so it should insert the value right? Especially if I have confirmed that this value is also inside the ScheduledEntityInsertion. Schrödinger's TblCompaniesServicesId.

Comment: And I know this is off-topic but your entity names do not have to match table names.  I realize some database administrators like very long names and you may not have any choice.  But entities with names like Company, Customer,Contract might make you life much easier.

Comment: `dd($tblCompaniesServicesContracts);` also results in `-tblCompaniesServicesId: 12`, so the data in the variable is correct. It really looks like everything goes wrong at the `flush()`.

off-topic: yes, I completely agree, I usually keep my own column names short and simple. As well as keeping Entity names singular. Plural Entity names don't works so well with Symfony.

Comment: I put an if statement around the flush and it still gives the SQL error. It should only flush if tblCompaniesServicesId is not null. It did still flush, but it still errored because tblCompaniesServicesId is apparently null.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any old xml or yml Doctrine mapping files hanging around.  Possibly under Resources/config/doctrine.  They will interfere with your annotation directory.  I suspect you generated the entities using a mapping tool?  If so, Doctrine might think there is need a relation.  Sure acting like it.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Turns out someone else made another method inside TblCompaniesServicesContracts which does actually need a TblCompaniesServices entity. That function should be called instead of the function I called. Conclusion: the code is a mess and I don't know what exactly of the Entity to trust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know why it goes wrong, but a function which does require another entity should fix it. And that function should be called instead of the function you'd expect to use.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TblCompaniesServices", inversedBy="contracts")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tbl_companies_services_id", referencedColumnName="tbl_companies_services_id", nullable=true)
 */
private $service;

public function setService(?TblCompaniesServices $service): self
{
    $this->service = $service;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Even gladder that I was right (humor). And yes, the ORM really wants to work with objects.  Anytime you drop down to individual column ids you run the risk of problems.